# (Java Newbie - Panel Transitions) How do I switch between panels in a frame

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have the following simple code and I don't know how to modify it so as to have 3 separate panels to switch to, one for each button:

```
package TouristLocations;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;

public class buildApp extends JFrame {
  /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public static void main(String[] args){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
    frame.setSize(400,500);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    JLabel title = new JLabel("Locations");
    title.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 40));
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.gridwidth = 3;
    frame.add(title, c);

    JButton b1 = new JButton("View Locations");
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    c.gridwidth = 1;
    frame.add(b1, c);

    JButton b2 = new JButton("Insert Locations");
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 1;
    frame.add(b2, c);

    JButton b3 = new JButton("Help");
    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 1;
    frame.add(b3, c);

    TextArea text1 = new TextArea(15,40);
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 2;
    c.gridwidth = 3;
    frame.add(text1, c);

    frame.pack();


  }
}
```

thank you

Comment: @ user573382 maybe similair topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6010915/change-contentpane-of-frame-after-button-clicked

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you should consider using [JTabbedPane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [*How to Use Tabbed Panes*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html), you may want to look at [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html), mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654926/implementing-back-forward-buttons-in-swing/5655843#5655843) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654926/implementing-back-forward-buttons-in-swing/5657106#5657106).

Answer (score 0):

You should create a main container:

```
JPanel mainContainer = new JPanel();

//creation of each child
JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
```

... so each button must add those panels into the main container and resize new panel size, something like this:

```
//for button1:
mainContainer.add(panel1);
panel1.setSize(mainContainer.getSize());
```

... for button2 action, you must follow the same way above.