# Change contentpane of Frame after button clicked

Tags: java, swing

I want to be able to set a JFrame's contentpane after a button inside one of that frame's JPanels has been clicked.

My architecture consists of a controller which creates the JFrame and the first JPanel inside of it. From within the first JPanel I'm calling a method: setcontentpane(JPanel jpanel) on the controller. However, instead of loading the passed JPanel it does nothing but removing all Panels (see code below)

ActionListener inside of the first JPanel:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            controller.setpanel(new CustomPanel(string1, string2));
        }
```

Controller:

```
JFrame frame;

public void setpanel(JPanel panel)
{
    frame.getContentPane().removeAll();
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    frame.repaint();
}

public Controller(JFrame frame)
{
    this.frame=frame;
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Call revalidate, then repaint. This tells the layout managers to do their layouts of their components:

```
JPanel contentPane = (JPanel) frame.getContentPane();

contentPane.removeAll();
contentPane.add(panel);
contentPane.revalidate(); 
contentPane.repaint();
```

Better though if you just want to swap JPanels is to use a CardLayout and have it do the dirty work.

Comment: Full of Eels: Thanks, I think I'll use the CardLayout. I still find it hard to understand why my code didn't work though.

Comment: @Julian, what do you mean you don't understand why your code didn't work? You didn't invoke the revalidate() method. If you mean you don't understand why revalidate() is necessary then think what happens if you add 100 components to the panel? It doesn't make sense to layout the components after every add(...) or remove(...) statement. So instead you tell the layout manager when you are finished making changes by using the revalidate() method. Then layout is only done once.

Answer (score 4):

I found a way to do what I outlined above.

Implementing the setpanel method like this:

```
public void setpanel(JPanel panel)
{
    frame.setContentPane(panel);
    frame.validate();
}
```

did the trick in my case.

I'm sure that I still need to fix something within my code, since pack() still shrinks the window, but at least the method posted above works.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you change a frame's containment hierarchy, you have to call `pack()`.

From the docs:

> Causes this Window to be sized to fit
>   the preferred size and layouts of its
>   subcomponents. [...] The Window will
>   be validated after the preferredSize
>   is calculated.

Comment: Doing this just causes the frame to shrink to the smallest possible size. Is it possible that my passed JPanel is for some reason not accessible from within the method?

I checked that the constructor of the passed panel is getting called.

Comment: @Julian: No, the JPanel is likely in the JFrame. It's more likely that your preferredSizes have not been set or you're not using layout managers correctly.

Comment: Where would one normally use layout managers incorrectly? I haven't paid much attention to them until now.

Comment: @Julian: that's the problem then -- pay attention to them and use them. The tutorials on how to use them is pretty decent.