# Link to other panel once i clicked the button

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout, actionlistener

now i have 3 Java files which are .
i have 2 buttons on TrainAndCOnductor. my purpose is , when i click on 1st button it will open my The Conductor panel.

```
public class JavaApplication1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TheConductor form = new TheConductor();
        form.setVisible(true);
    }
}
//Train And Conductor
    public class TrainAndConductor extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /** Creates new form TrainAndConductor */
    public TrainAndConductor() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("Train Driver");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setText("Conductor");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 282, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 282, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 23, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jButton2))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        add(TheConductor);
        TheConductor.setVisible(true);

//The Conductor
public class TheConductor extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /** Creates new form TheConductor */
    public TheConductor() {
        initComponents();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how your layout is organised. You can use a JTabbedPane or [CardLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) to achieve this.

Comment: See also this `CardLayout` [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654926/implementing-back-forward-buttons-in-swing/5655843#5655843).

Comment: @Andrew Thompson: I had since edited the link; and thank you for noticing. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
   secondPanel.setVisible(true);
}
```

and if you are not adding it before then you have to also add it like:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
   add(secondPanel);
   secondPanel.setVisible(true);
}
```

---

Try this:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    TheConductor conduct = new TheConductor();
    add(conduct);
    conduct.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: sorry, it cannot work , it says non-static method setVisible(boolean) cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: @George Lim: is your `TrainAndConductor` variable global and accessible by this method?

Comment: @George: You must create the `TrainAndConductor` panel before, and then call the method setVisible on the object: `myTrainAndConductorObject.setVisible(true);`

Comment: @George: We know that. It would be helpful if you could provide more code.

Comment: i have edited the code, some codes are for other purpose just ignore it.

Comment: @George: okay. Now just create constructor of the TheConductor class in actionPerformed and in the constructor of TheConductor use `setVisible(true);`. Note that you also have to provide size of TheConductor may be you are providing in initComponents() of TheConductor.

Comment: thanks man . it works now . and also last question. what method should i implement to close the TrainAndConductor Panel.

public TheConductor() {
        initComponents();
        setVisible(true);
        //close action

Comment: @George: it depends on meaning of close. If you just wanna hide and preserve data then use `setVisible(false);`

Comment: it works after i remove a bunch of code in TheConductor which are below. 

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new TheConductor().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

Comment: what i meant was , let say there are 2 panels there, once i click the button on the 1st panel and it brings me to the second panel in the mean time, it will also close my first panel.

Comment: @George: add `setVisible(false);` after you create TheConstructor object in first frame. This will hide first frame.

Comment: sorry sir, i dont get it, where should i add setVisible(false); ?

Comment: @George: `private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    TheConductor conduct = new TheConductor();
    setVisible(false);
}`

Comment: @Harry hi, but my current setVisible is true , how can i set it to false again ?


    `private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        TheConductor conduct = new TheConductor();
        add(conduct);
        conduct.setVisible(false);`

Comment: `private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        TheConductor conduct = new TheConductor();
        conduct.setVisible(true);
        setVisible(false);
    }`