# CardLayout not working properly

Tags: java, swing, jsplitpane, cardlayout

I have written this simple Cardlayout example with Splitpane, Combobox and few other panels containing buttons and label.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class splitpane_test extends JFrame implements ItemListener {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    final static String BUTTONPANEL = "Card with JButtons";
    final static String TEXTPANEL = "Card with JTextField";
    JPanel cards;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                try {
                    splitpane_test frame = new splitpane_test();
                    //frame.addComponentToPane(frame.getContentPane());
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public splitpane_test() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane();
        contentPane.add(splitPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);


        JPanel comboBoxPane = new JPanel();
        String comboBoxItems[] = {BUTTONPANEL, TEXTPANEL};
        JComboBox cb = new JComboBox(comboBoxItems);
        cb.setEditable(false);
        cb.addItemListener(this);
        comboBoxPane.add(cb);
        splitPane.setLeftComponent(comboBoxPane);

        //Create the "cards".
        JPanel card1 = new JPanel();
        card1.add(new JButton("Button 1"));
        card1.add(new JButton("Button 2"));
        card1.add(new JButton("Button 3"));

        JPanel card2 = new JPanel();
        card2.add(new JTextField("TextField", 20));

        //Create the panel that contains the "cards".
        cards = new JPanel();
        cards.add(card1, BUTTONPANEL);
        cards.add(card2, TEXTPANEL);
        splitPane.setRightComponent(cards);
        cards.setLayout(new CardLayout(0, 0));
    }

    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.print("Event Triggered \n");
        CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) (cards.getLayout());
        cl.show(cards, TEXTPANEL);
    }
}
```

I can see the splitpane with combobox on left and other cardlayout panels on right. 
when i change the combobox items nothing is happening on right size. 
In order to verify if iam hitting the cardout i used the 
**System.out.print("Event Triggered \n");**
but the surprising thing i have seen is that its displaying twice for each combobox item change as if its calling twice

```
Event Triggered
Event Triggered
```

Can you please suggest me what iam doing wrong here and why event triggered is getting hit twice.
Thanks for all your time and help.

Comment: +1 for [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Set the layout manager before adding components.
2. Two items are changing state; one is being deselected, the other selected.  You would improve your debugging output with the following:

   `System.out.println("Event Triggered: " + e);`

You'll also need to account for the event switching the selection back--not all changes in the combo box should select `TEXTPANEL`.

Comment: I tried to replace combobox with JTree and see if it can do the same,but again it doesn't seems to work . 
`code CardLayout c1 = (CardLayout)(cards.getLayout());
  DefaultMutableTreeNode sel = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)tree.getLastSelectedPathComponent();
  if (sel.isLeaf()) {
   System.out.println(sel+e.getSource().toString());
   c1.show(cards ,sel.toString());
  }
`
I can see the correct Panel being called yet the cardlayout doesn't change .If i use the Panel name manually it work . Please suggest me the mistake i am doing. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Look at `DefaultMutableTreeNode.getUserObject()`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it doesn't seems to be working. 
`code
public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) {
  CardLayout c1 = (CardLayout)(cards.getLayout());
  DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)tree.getLastSelectedPathComponent();
  if (node.isLeaf()){
   System.out.println(node.getUserObject());
   c1.show(cards, (String) node.getUserObject());
  }`

Answer (score 4):

> Can you please suggest me what I am doing wrong here and why event triggered is getting hit twice.

If you look at the `ItemEvent`, you'll see that one item is being `DESELECTED` and the other is being `SELECTED`. Instead, listen for `ActionEvent`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432170/how-to-change-ui-depending-on-combo-box-selection/6432291#6432291), and select the correct card accordingly.

Addendum: If you implement the helpful changes in @Michael Brewer-Davis's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6540181/cardlayout-not-working-properly/6540242#6540242), then a suitable `ActionListener` is particularly straightforward:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JComboBox jcb = (JComboBox) e.getSource();
    CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) cards.getLayout();
    cl.show(cards, jcb.getSelectedItem().toString());
}
```