# JAVA Container and Component interaction

Tags: java, components, containers

So in JAVA, given that a Container can also be called as a component. Why cant i put a `JFrame`(Container) inside another `JFrame`(Container/component)?

Comment: A JFrame is supposed to be a top-level container (at the root of the containment hierachy). Why do you want to nest them?

Comment: i don't want to nest them i was just checking can a we put a container inside another container or does it depend on hierarchy.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17287248/jframe-inside-another-jframe and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6891868/placing-jframes-inside-jframes

Comment: so lower level containers can be placed inside upper level containers hierarchy wise ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can put a container inside of another container.

That is extremely common, one of the core principles of the component/container hierarchy and quite essential to build any kind of non-trivial UI.

However

- every component can have only one (direct) container. If you add it to a second one, it will be removed from its original container.
- JFrame is a top-level container. It cannot be contained in other containers.

Comment: so lower level containers can be placed inside upper level containers hierarchy wise ?

Comment: Not sure what "lower level" means. Placing a container (such as a JPanel) inside of another container (such as a second JPanel) makes up the "level" in the containment hierarchy, doesn't it?