# Deleting a JPanel inside a JPanel... inside a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I am trying to make a slideshow-like application in Java using NetBeans.

I have a JFrame (the main window) and inside it are two buttons (back and next) for navigation, and a JPanel (`mainPanel`) which acts as holder of the 'slides' of the app. I am also using custom JPanel (`SlidePanel`) objects which are then placed inside the `mainPanel`. Some of these `SlidePanel` objects have JPanels within them.

Now, I've been able to place these `SlidePanel` objects inside the `mainPanel` and also navigate through them (for example, if I click the next button, `SlidePanel 1` would be replaced by `SlidePanel 2`, or if I click the back button, `SlidePanel 2` would be replaced by `SlidePanel 1`.) I've done this by using the `removeAll()`, `revalidate()`, and `repaint()` methods.

The problem starts here. The third `SlidePanel` object contains a JPanel inside it. What happens when you get to the third `SlidePanel`, it works fine. But from there, if you click the back button (which takes you back to `SlidePanel 2`), the JPanel from `SlidePanel 3` remains on the screen, with the components inside `SlidePanel 2` adjusted to fit the `mainPanel`.

What should I do to fix this?

**EDIT:** Thank you very much to all those who answered. I tried CardLayout on a dummy project and it worked fine. Now, all I have to do is add it to the original one. Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest to use [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for that, rather as add and remove `JPanels` on the `Runtime` example for `CardLayout` and together with your idea could be [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8371896/714968)

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you use a different layout manager (e.g. `CardLayout`); let the layout manager worry about juggling it's components.