# What's so special about CardLayout vs manual adding/removal of JPanels?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, cardlayout

There have been many times on StackOverflow where a user asks a question like this...

> I have a main `JPanel` that contains a child `JPanel`. When the user clicks a
>   button, the child `JPanel` should change to a different `JPanel`. How can I
>   achieve this.

More often than not, the user has actually tried to implement this problem, but can't get it working.

Whenever I answer this question, I tell them to do something like this (put simply)...

```
JPanel myFrame = new JPanel();
myFrame.remove(oldPanel);
myFrame.add(newPanel);
```

I see this as quite a legitimate answer, and I personally have used this in many of my own Java projects without problem. However, I always get downvotes for my answer, and everyone just says "Use a `CardLayout`".

So my question is, why is everyone so fascinated with `CardLayout`, to the point where my answer deserves a downvote? Why should I choose to use a `CardLayout` rather than adding/removing panels using my code above?

As a further question, would you still be suggesting `CardLayout` for interfaces that have dynamic JPanels. For example, most of my programs implement a custom plugin framework where there could be many hundreds of `JPanels`, but I only load and display the panels as they are actually required. For the normal use of the program, most of the panels would never actually be loaded or required. For this type of scenario, would my coding approach be the best solution, as I understand that `CardLayout` would require me to actually create all of the `JPanels` even though most will never be used?

Comment: I think you've done a good job phrasing your question in a constructive way.  I hope it doesn't get closed.

Comment: Thanks for that - I deliberately tried to make it a constructive question, and am glad to get some good feedback.

Comment: *"but I only load and display the panels as they are actually required."* Lazy instantiation can be used with `CardLayout` as well, and it supports 1000s of panels.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewThompson, I wasn't sure if that was supported with `CardLayout`, so was kinda throwing that in there to get some verification whether it did/didn't support such an activity.

Comment: @WATTOStudios Please don't approve [suggested edits like this](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/827006). If needed, refer to this [meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157423/165773) for details.

Comment: Apologies for that, I do remember that post, unfortunately I was reviewing on my mobile and the wrong button was pressed. I know there were a few of these, but am glad it requires multiple people for the final verdict. I really should post on Meta about a mobile-friendly review page, or an undo button.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- With CardLayout, it's easier to have loose coupling (though not impossible with roll your own)
- With CardLayout, the preferredSize of the card-holder is that of the largest card it holds.
- CardLayout is harder to fark-up, and allows almost trivial contiguous component swapping its `next()` and `prev()` methods.
- You can easily associate the desired component with a constant -- no need to have to create a `Map<String, Component>` for this purpose as it's already there for you. I've not infrequently used enums for this.
- No need to remember to call `repaint()` and `revalidate()` when swapping components.
- It's built for and allows for easy re-use of components.

Comment: Thanks for the great response, I had a gut feeling about some of these points, and it presents a number of good cases for using `CardLayout`.

Comment: Related example may be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5655843/230513) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6432291/230513).

Answer (score 8):

`CardLayout` has been thoroughly tested and proven to work. It correctly acquires the [component-tree lock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getTreeLock%28%29) and performs component [validation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#validate%28%29) in order to ensure that nothing can go wrong. Your solution, while it may work most of the time, will fail under certain circumstances.

This all boils to reinventing the wheel: Why would you want to when such a time-tested class is already available?

Comment: This raises a few good points too, thanks for your feedback. I can certainly understand that it would help to provide some assurance against failures. In regards to reinventing the wheel, I guess it never occurred to me that `CardLayout` would be suitable for my purposes, and I do a fair amount of tinkering at the low level of Java so it wasn't really a big leap for me to use the lower-level `add()`/`remove()` options. Thanks for the good points!