# Java GUI Game Menu

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, menu

I'm trying to work on a project - we are creating a little game with a GUI.
I decided to start by working on a 'main menu'. Essentially, there will be buttons such as "Single Player", "Help", etc...

I've made the GUI with the menu, etc. I have added listeners as well.

How do I approach the problem now? If someone clicks, say, 'Single Player', I'd like the screen to change to display a title showing "SINGLE PLAYER" and get rid of the main menu. 
What do I need to do in my `actionPerformed()` method to get this effect?

I guess I will be able to work it out from there.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

- best of all options could be use [JMenuItem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) to interact with Cards layed by [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html), options are described incl. images in the tutorial
- best of questions asked [about CardLayout ever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10694584/whats-so-special-about-cardlayout-vs-manual-adding-removal-of-jpanels)

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be to put the corresponding windows onto a separate Jpanel and have one master panel in your gui. Whenever the user clicks on a button, you remove whatever was on the master panel add the corrseponding panel, then repaint the gui.

something like this:

```
    if (e.getSource() == button){           
                masterPanel.removeAll();            
                masterPanel.add(newWindow);                 
                this.setVisible(true);
                this.repaint();     
            }
```