# Java applet not showing correctly

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jar, applet

I have made a Java Applet.

```
<applet code=gui.clientGUI.MyApplet.class 
        archive="QTminer.jar"
        width=400 height=200>
</applet>
```

my jar looks like this:

[image]

this is my simple code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class MyApplet extends JApplet {

    public void init() {
        try {
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    initUI();
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void initUI() {
        getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 5, 5));

        JButton btnStartApplication = new JButton("Start Application");
        btnStartApplication.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                SS oi = new SS();
                oi.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(btnStartApplication);
    }
}

class SS extends JWindow {

    private JLabel lblNewLabel;
    private JLabel label;

    public SS() {
    setBounds(new Rectangle(0, 0, 883, 590));
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Welcome", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    lblNewLabel.setForeground(Color.RED);
    lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI", Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, 24));
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(0, 313, 883, 41);
    getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);

    label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/gui/resources/Qtminer_background.jpg")));

    label.setBounds(0, 0, 883, 592);
    getContentPane().add(label);

    setVisible(true);
}
}
```

My problem is that when running in eclipse everything works, but when running in browser i get a NullPointerException right on the load of the image icon:

```
label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/gui/resources/Qtminer_background.jpg")));
```

Comment: I guess you can't expect a JWindow to pop up (in a browser) that runs independently from the JApplet... That would be pretty user-unfriendly,  too. Why don't you just make everything inside one JApplet? - Remove the previous panel and add the new one. Btw, maybe you will get better help than my comment if you post a [mcve]. You really just need to show us a compilable example that launches a new JWindow after a button click inside a JApplet.

Comment: Not sure if this is the cause of your problem, but you should replace spin-loops like `while(object.showable==false);` with [wait](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait--)/[notify](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify--) or with [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html).

Comment: I'll try, but if you want you can try to compile this code, is fully compilable.

Comment: @LuxxMiner *"Remove the previous panel and add the new one."* (shudder) A `CardLayout` is almost always a better solution.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Oh yeah, that's right. I always thought there's not really a big difference between doing it manually and with `CardLayout`. I can't believe I never just [googled](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10694622/4857909) it :P. Thx for the advice.

Comment: ***"My splash screen loses his background image! In Eclipse my splash screen shows correctly"***  Then apparently the image is either not on the run-time class-path of the applet, or not at the place within the class-path that the code is requesting it from.  Show the applet element used to launch the applet (particularly the `codebase` and `archive` fields) as well as the content listing for each Jar.

Comment: And a tip: Add @LuxxMiner (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.  ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson, thanks for the tip.

I didn't understand what should i show, pardon, can you help me?

Comment: *"I didn't understand what should i show"*  Are you launching the applet using HTML?  Copy/paste the part that shows the applet element used to launch it.  That will tell us what Jars are on the class-path.  Then we need to know the Jar content.  If you don't understand something I write, please be specific about what you don't understand.  I don't like having to write an essay in reply to a vague 'I don't understand'..

Comment: @AndrewThompson sorry for the vagueness.

HTML CODE and a view of my jar have been added to my post, you can see it in the first lines

Comment: *"..and a view of my jar"* Rather than a screenshot of WinRAR (which BTW - does not even show the resource in question, just the parent directory), use the Jar tool on the command line to get a complete listing.  Something like `jar -tvf QTminer.jar`

Comment: @AndrewThompson done, i hope it's good now

Comment: The path in code matches the actual path as far as I can see..  But `ServerSplashScreen.class.getResource("/gui/resources/Qtminer_background.jpg")` .. what is `ServerSplashScreen`?  Try instead `this.getClass().getResource("/gui/resources/Qtminer_background.jpg")`

Comment: @AndrewThompson got some news, check the edit in my original post.

Using the original code i posted, strange things happen.

Comment: @LuxxMiner i edited my post, please check it out and if you can help me.

Comment: @AndrewThompson i edited my post, please check it out and if you can help me.

Comment: 1) Remove the constructor.  Do everything of relevance in the `init()` method and ensure it is done on the EDT.` 2) `MyApplet app=new MyApplet();
                app.setVisible(true);`  ?!?  You already have an instance of the applet (which will automatically be set visible)!  There is no sense to creating one here.

Comment: I made en edit to include code that implements my suggestions on how to arrange the applet parts.  A few comments:  1) It creates an image in code to allow other people to run it.  2) The original code wouldn't run for me until I create the image, then it worked for me as is.  But the code in the constructor was 'dangerous' in that it was being called off the EDT.  So that may have been the problem in the browser.  3) Try the code I posted in a) your IDE. b) in the browser completely unchanged. c) in the browser, adapted for your image. 4) .. but

Comment: 4) .. but popping a free floating window out of an embedded applet suggests it would be better to create the GUI in a `JFrame` or a `JWindow` as needed, then launch that directly from a link using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  Launched using JWS it will be simpler & more reliable to deploy and make for a better user experience.

Comment: @AndrewThompson code works with image created in code.

but the problem comes back when i create label this way:

label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(/path/img.jpg)));

Comment: Be sure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show.  If there is no output at the default level, raise the level and try it again.  But again, this will be better done without the applet.

Comment: @AndrewThompson

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-2" java.lang.NullPointerException at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)

it seems that it's not founding my jpg file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My OS denied access to the local file jar.

Testing the applet on a real web-server made it work.

Solved!