# Switch to specific JPanel using Cardlayout

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jpanel, cardlayout

I've started working on a Java desktop application using netbeans. I have 7 different screens and to represent them I am using `JPanel`. One JPanel to represent each of them and one to contain all of them(named as mainPanel), which is inside a JFrame. mainPanel uses `Cardlayout` for the purpose of switching between screens(JPanels). I built all this interface using netbeans ui widgets i.e. drag drop.

**LayOut**

```
JFrame
    mainPanel (Jpanel) CardLayout
        Child1 (JPanel)
        Child2 (JPanel)
        .
        .
        .
        .
        Childn (Jpanel)
```

I know that one can switch screens using `JPanel.next()` and `Jpanel.previous`. but they can only be used when switching is to be done among consecutive screens i.e. if you have to switch to an immediate neighbour. There's also a method `JPanel.show()` to go to a specific screen but problem is that it takes a parameter `name` which is a `String` you associate when you add it to mainPanel using `JPanel.add()` function. I've added everything using drag and drop, so I don't know what `String` gets associated, if it does.
Although it looks very primitive and I've already done it without `Cardlayout` but this time, Cardlayout is a requirement.

Help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well... I got the answer.
The thing is, when you add something through interface, code for it is autogenerated which is hidden by default. So, I had to look into the autogenerated code for associated string. by default it is card1, card2, card3 and so on.

The example in answer by trashgod is exactly what I want but not the way i want. It has manually associuated the string in custom Jpanel. But it made me think of looking into the autogenerated code. So, thank You very much :)

Now what I need to do is like

```
 mainPanel.show (gameHome, "Card3");
```

Answer (score 6):

This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6432291/230513) uses a `JComboBox` to change cards. The example extends `JPanel` to add a name, but `Component` has `getName()` and `setName()` methods as an alternative. See also this  related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5657106/230513).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, use a [ViewSwitcher](http://fhmp-java.blogspot.co.nz/2012/06/ive-come-across-many-answers-on.html)

It's better suited for what you are trying to do here.