# Switching JPanel with cardlayout using button from other JPanel new to java

Tags: java, jpanel, actionlistener, cardlayout

Is't possible to use 3 different buttons that is placed on top panel to switch 3 different panels on the bottom panel? and also the 3 different panels are from other classes?Sorry for noob question i'm just new on using this layout and i can't make my program work.I don't exactly know how the actionlistener work on this. Please give me an example to get through this.

Comment: Examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5655843/230513) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6432291/230513).