# Jpanel.add(Jpanel) is not responding?

Tags: java, swing, applet, awt, jpanel

Ok, i will try to make this as clear as i can.

i have FrIndex with a layout like below.
[image]

when i created an event where the first button is clicked, the Red Panel will be removed and replace with another panel that i have in the same package.

so this is my code.

```
void CallMocChiaKhoa() {
    pnMocChiaKhoa p = new pnMocChiaKhoa();
    pnMain.removeAll();
    pnMain.add(p);
    pnMain.validate();        
}
```

normally this code would work just perfectly fine..i did this before with another similar project.

can anyone help?

Comment: I think you should add the java tag.
That would get your question more attention.

Comment: i guess this is swing? can you share the code where you are attaching a listener? the code you pasted could mean anything..

Comment: @rethab yes this is Swing, im using netbean 7.3, somehow it added another swingswing layout extension to my project ...my other project didnt have it, does it make any different becuz of this extra extension?

Comment: @zBaoAnhLe that depends on what you extension is doing to your project. Please try to make a: http://sscce.org/

Comment: you may be missing a call to repaint();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah i figured it out...you just have to add in one more line:

```
pnMain.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
pnMain.removeAll();
```

and it work perfectly...thanks guys for your help! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`CardPanel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for this, as suggested in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5655843/230513). Each button's `ActionListener` would need to know the `name` of the card it's meant to `show()`. The name can be stored in a field, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6432291/230513), or in the corresponding panel itself, using `setName()`.