# Java Swing Dynamic Field Selection

Tags: java, swing, combobox

I'm not sure how to ask this question, and I'm certain that there's some kind of other solution to the problem I'm having so if anyone can point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it.

In any case, the issue I'm having is that I have a String[] list (called "projects") that I'm using to populate a combo box.  I want to use the selection from the combo box to dynamically change the form fields listed in a GUI panel.

My approach, so far, isn't dynamic enough because I will have nearly 100 possible selections from the combo box when I'm done.  So far, I've been testing with 3 options in the box, but scaling it up to 100 will involve a lot of code, and I think there MUST be some other solution, right?  I just don't know what that solution is.

```
String[] projects = {"Select a project...", "Option1", "Option2", "Option3"};

String[] Option1= {"phone", "maxphv"};
String[] Option2= {"address1", "address2", "house", "predir", "street", "strtype", "postdir", "apttype", "aptnbr"
        , "city", "state", "zip"};
String[] Option3= {"phone"};

ArrayList<String> fieldslist, fieldslbllist;
```

Ideally, I'd like to take the name of the project selected from the projects String[] combo box and reference that name as the name of another list that contains the fields I want to display in the panel.

But I gather from reading on other questions that the name of a variable is irrelevant once the code is compiled.

At this point, I have a set of code to clear the panel and dynamically select the fields, but I still have to manually code the replacement for each of the 100 options.  That's not terrible, I suppose, but I think that there is probably a better way that I am unaware of.

```
public void resetFields() {
    fieldslist.clear();
    fieldslbllist.clear();
}

public void setFields() {
    if (project.getSelectedIndex() == 0) {
        resetFields();
    }
    else if (project.getSelectedIndex() == 1) {
        resetFields();
        for (int i = 0; i <= Option1.length; i++) {
            fieldslist.add(Option1[i]);
            fieldslbllist.add(Option1[i]+"lbl");
        }
    }
    else if (project.getSelectedIndex() == 2) {
        resetFields();
        for (int i = 0; i <= Option2.length; i++) {
            fieldslist.add(Option2[i]);
            fieldslbllist.add(Option2[i]+"lbl");
        }
    }
//... onward to 100
```

The above is just a loop that resets the display on selection of a new option in the combo box and then loops through the options in the OptionX String[] list and adds the values to the fields Array.

Is this a viable way to handle dynamic UI coding?  And, is there any way to set it up so I will only have to specify which fields belong to each value and then not have to code a section for each possible project.getSelectedIndex() value in setFields()?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html), seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6432291/230513), to change the form dynamically. Given the large number of alternatives, look for a hierarchical breakdown among the choices that might allow you to use two related controls, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3191882/230513).

[image]