# Need to create a WIZARD on Netbeans (jDialog vs CardLayout)?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I would like to create a "wizard" on a JDialog using the CardLayout, triggered by user pressing the New button from the menubar.  In Netbeans I have created a JDialog through which I have a series of jPanels in CardLayout format.  In my "New" menu item I wrote the following code to initiate the jDialog as follows,

```
 CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) jDialogNew.getLayout();
 cl.preferredLayoutSize(jDialogNew);
 cl.show(jDialogNew, "card1");
```

However, the compiler comes up with the following error,

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException:
    java.awt.BorderLayout cannot be cast to java.awt.CardLayout
```

If anyone is out there that can take me through creating a wizard on "Netbeans" I'd be eternally grateful

Comment: This [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654926/implementing-back-forward-buttons-in-swing/5655843#5655843) might make a good start on your [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Your jDialogNew has a BorderLayout set as its layout and and not a CardLayout, meaning that when you call getLayout() to try to fit it into a variable that cant hold a BorderLayout an exception is thrown. The classes are different so you cannot cast from one to another, causing a ClassCastException.

A possible solution to this is to set your own layout for the jDialogNew. I dont have code infront of me so I cant check myself, but try looking for a method like setLayout(), and pass in a new layout of your choice.

Comment: Thanks Numeron for your kind answer!  You see, I want to create a wizard dialog using a few JPanel under the JDialog.  I need the user to be able to browse through these JPanels through a series of next/previous buttons.  This operation is vitally important for me at this stage and I need to get it done asap.  Your kind assitance in resolving this issue is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

you can do with following

```
create JFrame -> Add "CARD LAYOUT"
```

add JPanels to project. Design JPanels. Customize init code of JFrame. Insert JPanels with `this.add(jpanel name)`. for all jpanels setVisible(false) - then setVisible true which jpanel you want to start with.

Answer (score 0):

The way I did it in Netbeans was very easy!  All I had to do was to was to introduce a separate JFrame in my resources package (being a part of my overall package) and in that JFrame I created a JPanel with the CardLayout, under which I created all my other JPanels relating to that top JPanel.  Now having the JFrame I could set my fixed canvas plus everything else I needed to construct and activate my CardLayout "Wizard" dialogue box! Then I had to call the new JFrame from with my application whenever the event was triggered. It made life a whole lot easier and it works just great!