# Swing: Click on a button in a frame, show another frame with different components

Tags: java, swing

I am developing an application which needs to pop up new `JFrame` B with different components, when I click on a button on `JFrame` A.  How do I achieve that?

I don't want to use the tabs.

Comment: Have you tried anything to solve the issue?

Comment: See also [`CardPanel`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654926/implementing-back-forward-buttons-in-swing/5655843#5655843).

Comment: `please solve my prob..` -- Sorry, that's not really what we're here for...We can get you started in the right direction though!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a [JDialog](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html) , problem solved!

See this java tutorial for more help : [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Comment: But in JDialog,we can't add the Jtables,textfields...etc

Comment: NO, We can add, the jdialog inherits from container class,as the javadoc says *A generic Abstract Window Toolkit(AWT) container object is a component that can contain other AWT components.*, and note that the jtextfield and jtables are inherited from AWT components.

Comment: I & most others can add pretty much any GUI component(s) we want to a `JDialog` or `JOptionPane` (or a `JApplet` or a `JWindow` or a tab in a `JTabbedPane` ..).  Just put all the components in a single `JPanel` and add that to the final top-level component.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure why no one has suggested CardLayout yet, but this is likely your best solution. The Swing tutorials have a good section on this: [How to use CardLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Comment: *"I'm not sure why no one has suggested CardLayout yet.."*  See trashgod's comment/link.

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell (a simple solution), you register a listener with the JButton and then have the listener perform the tasks you want it to perform:

```
setVisible(true) for one frame.
setVisible(false) for the other one.
```

Regards!

Comment: EW. What a disgusting resolution!

Comment: @mre A solution is a solution friend. As it said a SIMPLE solution, maybe i should have said a DISGUSTING solution? So, if it is a valid solution, why the downvote?

Comment: @mre: amen! who wants windows popping in and out?

Comment: @Mechkov: it was my down-vote, not his. Your solution is a user's nightmare, that's why.

Comment: A solution is solution. So no need for the downvote as it will solve the problem. it is up to the topic creator to decide what works for him/her. Again, starting a chain reaction here fellas...

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels As i said a solution is a solution, whether it is ugly or "pretty" So no call for a downvote since this is "a valid solution"

Comment: +1 since -1 is too harsh. The question is nebulous and this answer is not "disgusting".

Comment: I disagree. When there are much better solutions available, why suggest a bad one?

Comment: @IngoKegel, This solution is most certainly disgusting. It's promoting bad practice. And as far as usability goes, well...this solution pretty much throws that right out the window.

Comment: Bad practice to have modal dialogs? Really? and you're downvoting stuff on that basis?

Comment: I dont think you understand what "(a simple solution)" means? Means one of many that solves an issue but it is up to you to decide whether you want to implement it or not..It is a valid solution, so if you like it - implement it, if not use something else. Just because you drive your own car and someone else is being driven, does not mean they dont get to their destinations.

Comment: @mre I see you have added your downvote as well. OK, guys - you take our your anger on the people who spend time helping others - I'm out of here.

Comment: If proposing this approach (and I **don't** recommend it) please also point out the frames will probably need to be changed to use `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE)`.

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this would be to create another jFrame and then add a listener onto your button like so:

```
jFrameNew.setVisible(true);
```

This way you have a whole new frame to work with. If you want to just have a pop-up message you can also try using the jDialog frames.

Depending on which IDE you are using...for example Netbeans has a gui that makes designing interfaces slightly easier, so you can test out the different frames.

Comment: Don't even suggest secondary JFrames as that's not what their for. If a program needs new windows they should be dependent on the main window or dialogs. Better even still to use to use CardLayout though.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels As Mechkov is arguing for his solution (since ours are rather similar) I don't see why you downvoted this. It solves the problem, and I also mention dialogues. I read the authors question, "needs to pop up new JFrame-B" as he literally wants a new frame.

Comment: Is it better to give the OP what he "wants" or the correct solution for his problem?

Comment: It's unclear what exactly the OP "wants". He said as long as it doesn't involve tabs. I merely gave him an option. How do you know exactly what layout he wants?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels This is a downvote based on your personal design preference which I'm going to revert with a +1. Unjust downvotes are demoralizing.

Comment: @IngoKegel, All his downvotes are justified, whereas your upvotes are misleading and wrong.

Comment: @Ingo: No, my downvote is for the original poster to know not to use this solution but to use better solutions such as either CardLayout or JDialogs.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels But there is nothing WRONG with my solution. It is a solution. If, in theory your solution is better, it should receive more upvotes, no?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'm not saying these answers are good, but I strongly feel that they should not be downvoted. Upvote the good stuff.

Comment: @IngoKegel: Point taken. Post edited to allow removal of down-vote. To remove edit later.

Comment: If proposing this approach of multiple frames (and I **don't** recommend it) please also point out the frames will probably need to be changed to use `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE)`.

Comment: And still this post to be correct should mention that it is better to use JDialogs than to use multiple JFrames.