# GUI Architecture and Design in Java (Swing)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

I have spent the last several hours scouring the internet looking for examples and ideas on how to write a medium sized GUI in java.  I know a little about swing but that is all.  I don't know of any other way to develop a GUI in Java besides swing.  If you know of a different way that would be good too.  I also want to hand-write the GUI myself to allow for easier integration with our game and future refactoring.

We have written the entire business logic to a Tic Tac Toe game that has several features.  The gui needs to have several windows which can be navigated using simple buttons on the interface.  A very crude and water-downed version of what I am looking to do can be seen below:

[image: Main Menu] 
[image: Network Box]

[image: Game Board]

The Heart of my question is this:

**How do I architect the GUI using Swing and what general design is used?**

and some follow-up questions:
Is there a class for every window? Do I just use `setvisible` to make my windows appear and disappear after the buttons are pressed?

`re there any examples you all know of (github repos would be excellent! happy forking!) that could show me a good gui architecture/design?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can create multiple JPanels (or their extensions) place them in one container with CardLayout and switch cards when necessary.

Comment: Focusing on the GUI, I'd endorse @StanislavL's one-frame, multiple-panel approach. `CardLayout`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5655843/230513), is a good way to switch.

Comment: Do you know of any onlie examples of this?

Comment: I greatly apologize.  I didn't see your link earlier.  I was browsing from my phone and it didnt render before.  Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Also consider the [Model–View–Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller) pattern, discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513).

Comment: We are using a very similar architecture (basically MVC) for the overall game.  But I am no concerned with the overall architecture.  I am concerned about the architecture and design of simply the GUI.

Comment: I looked more indepth at your links.  They look very interesting.  I will look into examples.