# How to combine 3 GUIs

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtabbedpane

I have 3 separate GUIs that perform independent functions:

- ConverterGUI
- TransformerGUI
- GenerationGUI

How can I combine them together in such a way that they would look like tabs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a [`JTabbedPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html) See [How to Use Tabbed Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html) for details.

[image: tabbed pane]

Comment: maybe CardLayout and with JMenu could be an alternative

Comment: @mKorbel  Mmmm..  not convinced when the question states *"look like tabs"*, but maybe I am presuming too much.  It is me that expanded the tags from just `java` ( which might show how much presuming I did on that answer ;).

Comment: @lee yes no problem, no issue with that, [Cardlayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)  and [JTabbedPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html)

Comment: @Andrew Thompson :-), :-), :-)

Comment: @Andrew Thompson your bluntness is not required,all that is required is good directions in solving the problem.

Comment: @lee: I find Andrew's [advice](http://sscce.org/) helpful, and I frequently post the results here, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5655843/230513). See also this [Q&A](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2686/163188).

Comment: @lee Andrew's answer and comments are correct, clear and excellent describe, your comment could be childish :-)

Comment: Am sorry guys i've just being trying hard to get it and it seems to get more complicated. thank you for your time.

Comment: If there were any evidence of how hard you had tried (e.g. a code sample with a specific question as to how to achieve the next step) you might find all 3 of the people who have so far commented, willing to help further.  Please think it over.

Comment: what i can produce are my 3 gui codes, how to join them together seem like magic to me..but as u have adviced, i would try harder

Comment: OK...  If you can do it for 2, it should be easy for 3, right?  So first start thinking about trimming the problem down to just combining **2** GUIs.  Then thinking about it, `ConverterGUI` might have an input field for a number, a combo box for the units to convert, and a label for the output.  But again, if you can work out how to add a label to one tab, and a combo to another, the bigger task should be easy.  Or at least much easier.  The idea is, start small, and the first moment you strike a problem, post the code as it is and ask a specific question.

Comment: You're welcome.  Hope it goes well, and if it doesn't, please ask a new question.