# CardLayout - How to use previous() and next() using NetBeans GUI Builder?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans, cardlayout

Here is what I tried:

Dragged some JPanels onto a JFrame (using NetBeans inspector window).

In JFrame constructor, made all JPanels invisible using `.setVisible(false)`, except the one I want to show first.

It works and I can easily go from one to another by using some buttons with actionPerformed and adding `.setVisible(false)` to the current card and `.setVisible(true)` to the one I want to see.

What I wanted to do now is to use CardLayout `previous()` and `next()`, similar to a browser's back/forward. I also would like to reach to a panel from different places, i.e., two panels can link to the same one, so previous panel wouldn't always be the same.

I tried using the following code in an actionPerformed inside JFrame class:

```
CardLayout cardLayout = (CardLayout) this.getLayout();
cardLayout.previous(this);
```

However, it doesn't work. What am I missing? Is this supposed to do what I'm looking for?

Comment: See also this complete [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5655843/230513).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a variable `String previousCard` in your JPanel. When you go from CardA to CardB set `previousCard` variable to "CardA" or whatever the card's name is. So after setting this for all transitions from one card to other, the back buttons will always do the same thing.

```
cardLayouot.show(getContentPane(), previousCard);
```

Answer (score 3):

As you have  set the layout of your `JFrame` to `CardLayout`, you will need to use the parent container when using its `next()` & `previous()` methods. For `JFrame` the parent container  is the content pane. So change:

```
cardLayout.previous(this);
```

to

```
cardLayout.previous(getContentPane());
```