# Update a component from a grid panel through a Listener

Tags: java, swing, awt, actionlistener

How to update a component from a grid panel through a Listener?

I have the following problem:
I create a grid table in this way

```
public class gui {

JPanel gridPanel = new JPanel();
JPanel background = new JPanel();
JLayeredPane layeredPanel = new JLayeredPane();
...

public gui{
...
for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
            JPanel panel= new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            panel.setOpaque(false);
            gridPanel.add(panel);
            }


gridPanel.setOpaque(false);
layered.add(background,new Integer(1));
layered.add(gridPanel, new Integer(2));

JButton piece = new JButton( new ImageIcon("an image"));
JPanel panel = (JPanel)gridPanel.getComponent(0);
panel.add(piece);
...
}
```

Ok, this works good, but I want to add an Action Listener to JButton that allow to update the `gridPanel`, I thought of addign this in the builder of my GUI:

```
piece.addActionListener(new Listener(this));
```

I create a new class ActionListener in this way:

```
public class Listener implements ActionListener{
private gui gui1;
public movimentoListener(gui gui1){
    gui1=gui;       
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    JButton piece = new JButton( new ImageIcon("an other image"));
            JPanel panel = (JPanel)getGridPanel().getComponent(1); //obviously I've created getGridPanel
            panel.add(piece);
            gui.getGridPanel().repaint()
}
}
```

I want when I press the button my `actionPerformed` change the component 1 of my `gridPanel` with a new image but this code don't work, I try to search on the web but I've not found a solution.

Comment: don't do that this way, maybe someone ....

Comment: You use variable `gui` two times - but it is declared nowhere (just `gui1`). Note: use capital names for classes and lower case for variables/fields.

Comment: Is it a compile-time error or a runtime exception?

Comment: See also this [`GridButtonPanel`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7706684/230513).

Comment: Yes, I declare gui1 and the use gui in this code but it's only a typo because I rename the  original variable, but my code is right ;)

Yes, there is a runtime exception "NullPointerException" on

     JPanel panel = (JPanel)getGridPanel().getComponent(1)

But I don't understand why...

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on these threads:

[CardLayout display Next panel - java Swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13421809/cardlayout-display-next-panel-java-swing?rq=1)

[java swing dynamically adding components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6516478/java-swing-dynamically-adding-components?rq=1)

Wish it helps you.