# How to reload a JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, cardlayout

I'm a java newbie... I need to know how to `reload` a `JPanel`? I extended the `JPanel` class and created a panel that will run in a `cardlayout` in an Applet. I want this panel to `reload/refresh` after the user clicks a `button` in this panel. I tried including the `revalidate`() and `repaint`() methods (methods I don't understand well) in the `ActionListener` for the button but nothing happened. Can anyone throw some light on how to correctly refresh the whole panel?

Comment: please whats is reload, for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable

Comment: What do you mean by "reload" and "refresh" exactly? Show some code, explain with an example what you want to do.

Comment: refresh/reload/update all the components in the panel... some of the components are displaying info that is being updated through jdbc

Comment: you should just use the Graphics instance of the JPanel.

Comment: Let's take a JLabel for example, whose text is reloaded from the database. To make it display the new text, use label.setText(). For a JTable, use table.setModel(), or update the data in its model. For a JTextArea, setText(), etc.

Comment: @Manish Doshi s/he want to setText based on value from JDBC, then Graphics haven't something with

Comment: @user2108393 : If you are looking for something like, an event that can clear all the fields and other components of their previous values, you can have a look at this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13378672/1057230), hopefully this might be of some help.

Answer (score 21):

This works fine for me. But after an other

```
_panel.revalidate();
_panel.repaint();
```

Comment: first removeAll() to remove all components 

_panel.removeAll();
 _panel.revalidate();
      _panel.repaint();