# Array to JLabel

Tags: java, arrays, string, swing

I have two Packages with java Class

- PKStrings
- PkJforms

---

```
public class classWork {
    public String[] titleMenu={
        "A","B","C","D"
    };

    public int intOption;
}
```

I have `JFrame` with menu

- A click go jframe A,

  B click go jframe B,

  C  click go jframe C,

  D  click go jframe D

And other frame in same package 
`JFram01`, contains `JLabel`.

How to recognize if you click on "A" and show that position label?

Comment: *"A click go jframe A, 
   
   B click go jframe B, 
   
   C  click go jframe C,
 
   D  click go jframe D"*  Arrrgh!  See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)  For 'lots of views' this might best be done using a `CardLayout`.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15308365/418556) for how to achieve this using a `CardLayout` (and a `JOptionPane` to select cards).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I dont understand your need. "A click A go jframe A" doesnot make sense.
if you want to go to another jFrame when clicking a label
Try this

    private void yourlabelMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
          //  either you can hide the current jFrame by setting 
            jFrame.setVisible(false);
            newjFrame.setVisible(True);
                    or
            make these jFrames in 2 different classes that make simple invocations
        }
```

Comment: Check my Practice mediafire.com/?pjf7w6x9l6b62g8

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand u can use a public variable in your package and store value in it using the on click event on A, B, C .....

then access that info from the jfaram you want

e.g

```
public String pos ="";

A onclick event(){
   pos="A";
}


finally

if(pos.compareto("A")==0){
   jlabel.settext("A");
}
```

Comment: Check my Practice http://www.mediafire.com/?pjf7w6x9l6b62g8
in the class Classwork containts tittle pages if i click in jbutton  "add" the title set "add".

Comment: set title menu on operacionesframe.java from Array String titleMenu example "Suma" when click Jbutton Sumas(menuFrame.java).

Comment: import pkWorking.classWork;

String[] newMenu = new classWork().titleMenu;