# Separate JPanel files organization

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, cardlayout

I'm working on a school project. It's basically a small program that will help people choose best smartphone according to their preferences.

It'll be like, every page will ask a question, then user clicks next and it proceeds to next page.

What would be the best approach for it? I don't want too much code crammed into one file. So I'm thinking -

1. `JFrame` using `CardLayout`.
2. A separate `JPanel` for each page.

But I'll want to keep all panels in separate files of their own. Will that be a good idea? If yes, how should I approach going forward in pages? `setVisible(true/false)` in `ActionListener`?

Apologies for the noob question, I'm super new to Java and learning on my own.

Comment: *"Will that be a good idea?"* - YES. *"how should I approach going forward in pages? SetVisible(True/False) in ActionListener?"* - Don't worry about `setVisible`, simply let `CardLayout` take care of it, but you will need a `next` button of sorts, containing a list of pages in the order you want them displayed

Comment: Thanks!!! Can you elaborate a bit on the next button part because thats exactly what I was thinkning

Answer (score 2):

See [`CardLayoutDemo.java`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665156/calling-awt-frame-methods-from-subclass/5786005#5786005) for this simplistic example.

[image: Game view]  [image: High Scores view]

See [`CardLayoutExample.java`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15308365/418556) for a UI that is closer to what you'd expect for a wizard or survey.

See also how to:

- [Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)
- [Write an Action Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)