# Change Background and size of panels in card layout

Tags: java, swing, awt, layout-manager, cardlayout

I have some panels in a card layout container (no idea if that is correct terminology). I can't find a way to set the location, or size of these panels inside the container. I tried setBounds and setLayout(null) and I still can't get anything to change.
These are my fields and the constructor. I've gotten my frame working and I can see and use the buttons to change cards, but I really can't change much else about the cards. I set the two card panels two have different backgrounds, but they only make a small boarder of color around the button and leave it in the centre of the screen.

I also don't understand why this isn't pasting my code properly... So sorry!

```
public class TestPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();

private JPanel panelCont = new JPanel();

private JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();

private JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();

private static JButton but1 = new JButton("Change panels");

private static JButton but2 = new JButton("Change back");

public TestPanel() {

    panelCont.setLayout(cl);
    panel1.add(but1);
    panel2.add(but2);
    panel1.setBackground(Color.black);
    panel2.setBackground(Color.blue);
    panelCont.add(panel1, "1");
    panelCont.add(panel2, "2");
    cl.show(panelCont, "1");
    but1.addActionListener(this);
    but2.addActionListener(this);
    add(panelCont);
}
}
```

Thanks. I apologise in advance. I'm finding it hard to understand card layout.

Comment: To use code formatting, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form.

Comment: *"I tried setBounds and setLayout(null) and I still can't get anything to change."*  Don't use those methods.  Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  For a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or combinations of them, along with **layout padding** & **borders** for white space, to organize the components.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), the size of the panels depends on the layout of whatever container they are added to.

Answer (score 3):

A CardLayout respects the preferred size of the panels added to the layout. That is the size will  be the size of the largest panel added to the layout.

> I set the two card panels two have different backgrounds, but they only make a small boarder of color around the button and leave it in the centre of the screen.

The default layout for a panel is the FlowLayout. A FlowLayout by default has a 5 pixel horizontal/vertical gap around each component. So the preferred size of your panel is the size of the button plus the 5 pixel gap.

The panel is displaying correctly. When you add other components to the panel the size will change as required.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear where you `pack()` the enclosing `Window`. By default, `pack()` causes a panel having [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) to adopt the the size of the *largest* panel's preferred size, which is determined by the size of its contents. This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5655843/230513) uses `setPreferredSize()` to specify an arbitrary size, but you can override `getPreferredSize()` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513).

[image]