# Java sample of GUI with button bar and change of active panel

Tags: java, swing, button, panel

I learn quickly by examples...

Where can I find a Java sample of GUI with button bar and change of active panel?

I have one toolbar working and I use Netbeans but I cant figure how to put more than one panel on the same position (below the button bar) and switch them by clicking on the buttons.

Thanks

Comment: *I learn quickly be examples...* I believe another way of saying this is "I learn quickly by people giving me full code solutions without me understanding it at all"? My suggestion is don't use a GUI builder because they're bad practice. Build the GUI by yourself without the assistance of a GUI builder.

Comment: Can you provide an image of what your GUI looks like so far and try to point out more clearly what you actually want?

Comment: You may be looking for `CardPanel`, seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5655843/230513) in response to [Implementing back/forward buttons in Swing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654926/implementing-back-forward-buttons-in-swing).

Comment: "I learn quickly be examples... I believe another way of saying this is "I learn quickly by people giving me full code solutions without me understanding it at all"? My suggestion is don't use a GUI builder because they're bad practice. Build the GUI by yourself without the assistance of a GUI builder. – Josh M 1 hour ago"

No sir! I dont ask code to solve my program... I only ask for any sample code to wathc and learn. I learn better on this way. Thanks for your suggestion anyway

Comment: "Can you provide an image of what your GUI looks like so far and try to point out more clearly what you actually want? – Trust 1 hour ago"

Hello, this is my actual code:

http://www.beetxt.com/X5y/

Comment: "You may be looking for CardPanel, seen here in response to Implementing back/forward buttons in Swing. – trashgod 1 hour ago"

Thanks a lot trashgod!

Comment: Thanks to the tip of the CardPanel I found cool samples... thanks a lot Trashgod

Here 2 working samples, I hope it helps more people:
http://java.about.com/od/Layout_Managers/ss/Cardlayout-Example-Program.htm
and
http://inforux.wordpress.com/2009/03/19/java-practicando-con-cardlayout/

Comment: `Thanks to the tip of the CardPanel I found cool samples...` - start with the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Card Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html). I'm not sure why people link to personal examples. The tutorial provide an example with an explanation as well as a table of contents for all other topics related to Swing which is an important reference.