# Using back buttons for CardLayout in Java Swing GUI

Tags: java, swing, cardlayout

I'm trying to implement a back button in my GUI which goes to the previous card using an action listener and running the code

```
cards.previous(contentPane);
```

when the button is pressed.

My problem is that after clicking the back button, no matter which button I press on the GUI, it always goes to the card that I came from. So the numbers being the `JPanel`s

**2** --back--> **1** --*--> **2**

back and * (=anything) are the buttons that I press. Why does this happen?

EDIT: `App extends JFrame`

```
public App() {
    cards = new CardLayout();
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setLayout(cards);
    contentPane.add(new StartPanel(this));
}

public void next(JPanel p) {
    contentPane.add(p);
    cards.next(contentPane);
}

public void prev() {
    cards.previous(contentPane);
}
```

`StartPanel` has

```
public StartPanel(App app) {
    JButton btn2 = new JButton("2");
    JButton btn3 = new JButton("3");
    btn2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            app.next(new JPanel());
        }
    });
    btn3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            app.next(new JPanel());
        }
    });
    add(btn2);
    add(btn3);
}
```

My problem is that when I go from panel 2 to panel 1(`StartPanel`) by pressing the back button, then press `btn3`, it goes to panel 2 instead of panel 3.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Take a look at TrashGod's example in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5655843/4475997) to "Implementing back/forward buttons in Swing".

Comment: @MasterBlaster: I'm not doing a back/forward button. Only a back button then the option to choose which card to switch to.